# MouseJointDef libgdx - draw a trajectory line like Angry Birds

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

in libgdx game

I want to touchDown and then drag somewhere and then on the release (touchUp) apply a directional force based on the distance and direction from the target body. When you touchdown the target body stays still and then on touchup the force is applied along the desired trajectory.

(very similar to Angry birds - where you get to see the trajectory in dotted lines for the target body when you hold hack the slingshot - I want to do the same)

So I guess that this might not be the hardest thing to do but given a few options Im leaning towards using a MouseJointDef but its an immediate force applied (i.e. the target moves immediately - I want it to stay still and then once the touchup event happens then apply the force)

Whats the easiest way to draw the trajectory also? Im using Box2D also.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a class that inherits `InputAdapter` class, then create an instance of it and register it to listen the touch inputs.

```
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(inputAdapter);
```

There are 3 methods to handle the touch events `touch_down`, `touch_dragged` and `touch_up` that you have to override.

In `touch_down`, check the touching position to whether is in the birds area or not. If it is, make a boolean flag true.

In `touch_dragged`, check the flag above and if it was true, calculate the distance of the touch position relative to the bird shooting center and the shooting angle.

In `touch_up`, you can order to shoot with the calculated amounts by calling

```
    body2shoot.applyLinearImpulse(impulse, body2shoot.getWorldCenter());
```

There is no need to `MouseJointDef` to move the `body2shoot`. Just set the transform of `body2shoot` in touching position to be dragged in each cycle of render.

For calculating the trajectory I wrote a class like this:

```
public class ProjectileEquation
{
public float gravity;
public Vector2 startVelocity = new Vector2();
public Vector2 startPoint = new Vector2();

public ProjectileEquation()
{   }

public float getX(float t)
{
    return startVelocity.x*t + startPoint.x;
}

public float getY(float t)
{
    return 0.5f*gravity*t*t + startVelocity.y*t + startPoint.y;
}
}
```

and for drawing it just I set the `startPoint` and `startVelocity` and then in a loop I give a `t` (time) incrementally and call `getX(t)` and `getY(t)`.

Comment: @Aliaaa Although the topic is quite old but I want to ask how do you calculate the the impulse you want to apply to the body since bodies have different mass..etc. an example would be great!

Comment: @george I didn't invented this formula it's physics basic formula for moving an object with gravity affected:

x = v0 * t + x0;
y = 0.5 * a * t^2 + v0 * t + x0;

Comment: I understand that its a formula. I've tried following the same example from here http://blog.gemserk.com/2012/07/03/drawing-a-projectile-trajectory-like-angry-birds-using-libgdx/ but it works for drawing a sprite but when it comes to moving the ball it does not quite work. That's why I wanted to ask what do you pass in the impulse where you say applyLinearImpulse. A complete example would be great!